# How to emphasize certain words in subtitles using mencoder?

Tags: video, avi, subtitles, video-conversion, mencoder

I'm using "mencoder" application to add subtitles to an AVI file. In the subtitles, there are certain words I want to emphasize by making them appear either in bold or in italics. I've tried surrounding them with HTML code but it doesn't work. I've tried both .srt and .ssa files with mencoder. How to emphasize certain words in subtitles using mencoder?

Answer (score 1):

Save your subtitle in an ASS format (e.g. you can create one with the free Aegisub editor) and then make sure to add the following options to *mencoder*:

```
-ass -vf ass,fixpts
```

You may also want to specify the subtitle's code page (in this example UTF-8) by adding these options:

```
-subcp utf8 -utf8
```